# Is it possible to set Android NFC Device ID randomly?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm interested in using NFC for anonymous transactions, but a necessary property is that separate transactions must not be linkable.  I noticed that the NFC protocols involve device identifiers, which *may* be chosen randomly on each transaction, but in most cases are unique and stable.

Is there any way in Android to specify or anonymize the device's NFC identifier?  I wasn't able to find anything from looking at the Android docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of the NFC hardware and firmware. There is no Android API for configuring this.